# Why use Dart as a front end developer?

Tags: dart

I just wanted to get a view on why one should use DART over JS, specially if you are working on the front-end; the Dart VM isn't even built into Chrome.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Don't worry about Chrome, it will be shipped within Chrome at some point when the stable 1.0 is out.

A couple of reasons why you might want to choose Dart over plain JavaScript for front-end development:

- [Better DOM API](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/improving-the-dom/)
- [Being more productive](http://www.dartlang.org/#productive-tools)
- Simpler and clearer semantics
- Lexical closures
- Libraries and a package manager
- Optional static typing
- Literally tons of little details that as a whole makes it a far nicer experience (named parameters, arrow functions, etc.)

You might want to read this chapter as it explains various things that Dart can do: http://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/ch02.html

You can also read this answer to the question ["*Does Dart have any useful features for web developers?*"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/164273/does-dart-have-any-useful-features-for-web-programmers/164304#164304)